# Cannot read contents when XML has 2 wrappers

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

This code works fine when you remove the `<data>` wrapper, from the XML and the nodes, but when you add it, like below, i get 0 results.

```
  -- Declare XML variable
  DECLARE @data XML;

  -- Element-centered XML
  SET @data =
  N'
  <data xmlns="test.xsd">
    <subdata>
      <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Allied Industries</name>
      </customer>
      <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Trades International</name>
      </customer>
    </subdata>
  </data>';

  -- Using the query() method
  SELECT T.customer.query('id').value('.', 'INT') AS customer_id,
         T.customer.query('name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS customer_name
  FROM @data.nodes('data/subdata/customer') AS T(customer);
```

But works fine when i do it like this:

```
  -- Element-centered XML
  SET @data =
  N'
    <subdata>
      <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Allied Industries</name>
      </customer>
      <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Trades International</name>
      </customer>
    </subdata>
 ';

  -- Using the query() method
  SELECT T.customer.query('id').value('.', 'INT') AS customer_id,
         T.customer.query('name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS customer_name
  FROM @data.nodes('subdata/customer') AS T(customer);
```

Does anyone know how or why I'm not getting results in the first example, when the `<data>` parent wrapper is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the number of "wrappers" around your XML data. The issue is: your first sample defines an **XML namespace** (`xmlns="test.xsd"`) on the `<data>` node, but your query isn't respecting that.

You need to change your query to be something like this:

```
-- Using the query() method
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'test.xsd')
SELECT 
    T.customer.query('id').value('.', 'INT') AS customer_id,
    T.customer.query('name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS customer_name
FROM 
    @data.nodes('data/subdata/customer') AS T(customer);
```

Then you'll get results....

Without this XML namespace declaration, your query would work just fine - two wrappers or more doesn't matter at all..

Comment: ya it did, thanks.. I also have another issue with this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` , when it starts at the top i get an error saying `cannot change encoding type on xml`, if you know it quickly, how do you get by this when your xml file comes with this at the top?

Comment: @ZeeTee: I believe if you prefix your XML data with an `N'` then it doesn't like the utf-8 declaration (because it's now a `NVARCHAR` string, thus using UCS-2 Unicode encoding). Either drop that XML declaration line, or drop the `N'` prefix .

Comment: Yup, you're awesome, that (removing N') did the trick also.. thanks!

Comment: @ZeeTee: <hehe> thanks! 25 years of experience do teach you a trick or two :-) So it's probably more "old age" than "awesome" - but thanks anyways!